# Laravel 8: How to style output at Models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to check if the *status* of users is Active or not. So in order to do this, I've added this piece of code to my Model `User.php`:

```
public function isActive()
    {
        if(($this->status) == 1)
        {
            return "<strong style='color:green'>Active</strong>";
        }
        else
        {
            return "<strong style='color:red'>Deactive</strong>";
        }
    }
```

And at the Blade, I get result by saying:

```
<td>{{ $user->isActive() }}</td>
```

But this will return this:

[image]

So the question is, how can I add some inline styles to the output of `isActive()` method ?

Comment: You can try this - `<td>{!! $user->isActive() !!}</td>`, Refer [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data) for explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you wouldn't return markup from you model as you're mixing concerns.

You would be 'better' using the value of your `isActive()` method in your blade view.

```
<td>
    <strong style="color:{{ $user->isActive() ? 'green' : 'red' }}">
        {{ $user->isActive() ? __('Active') : __('Inactive') }}
    </strong>
</td>
```

Your `isActive()` method would then just return a boolean value:

```
public function isActive()
{
    return $this->status == 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the specialchars, laravel blocks the specialchars to avoid something like mysql injection, css manupulation cause by injection of specialchars.
readmore about html specialchars here:https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

to displaying unescaped data in laravel u can use the code bellow

```
{!! your-code !!}
```

learn more at laravel doc
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data

Answer (score -1):

instead of using

```
{{ $user->isActive() }}
```

try this

```
{!! $user->isActive() !!}
```

By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlspecialchars, If you do not want your data to be escaped you can use {!! !!}
You can read more about that in laravel documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data

Comment: Please explain why.

Comment: You can read the part of laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data

Comment: Mate, I know. But your answer is so vague it'll likely get removed. Keeping with the _teach a man to fish_ saying, you are not teaching anyone. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does.